# Can't open latex on windows 10

Tags: miktex

I have installed MikTex2.9 on my PC using Windows 10. Now I want to use latex so I can create a document, but I have so many folders and I don't understand which file I should open.

Comment: Actually, there is no need to open files in MiKTeX directories.  Open and edit **your** working tex file in a directory of your choice and compile with `latex` or `pdflatex`.

Comment: LaTeX is not actutally an editor, LaTeX just provides the functionallity to build `tex` files. It sounds like you are looking for an Editor like TeXMaker (http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/) or TeXStudio (http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I can do that but how do I get auto script? I should not write all the comands it should do it for me.

Comment: Now you can make `pdflatex yourfile.tex` to obtain `yourfile.pdf` The .tex file is just a .txt file with another extension, so you can make it with any plain text editor, but suggested editors are better  because they  run the compilers for you and more.

Comment: A working  `yourfile.tex` file to start : `\documentclass{article}\begin{document} Hello, world. \end{document}`

Comment: I made a video tutorial years ago, maybe it helps you with the first steps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FxKtwdob2RQ. In addition I suggest to rear a book if you don't have a friend that could show you the first steps with LaTeX. I myself found the first steps with LaTeX very hard just by googeling and so on.

Comment: @Rico also Miktex comes with TeXworks